# android quiz game method selection

Tags: android

I am new to android and i want to build a quiz game for practice. I thought of creating question packages, each containing up to 1000 questions which the players will be able to download. I am thinking to insert the questions in a database (SQlite database) so each time I get a random number from 1 to 1000 for example i ll just use a query to search for the question with that id.

Some friends told me I should use xml files for the questions cause it would be easier to download the packages to each players device. But wouldnt that force me to search for the question with the right id in the entire xml and thus take alot more time than simply asking for a record with a specific id from a database?

Other consern is the communication with my server. What i m trying to say is, i read i should be using a a RESTful service but here is my question. I know that its easy to download an app from the store and view its source code. So whats stopping the guy who does that from seeing my database credentials inside the apps code and being able to have access to my remote server where all my clients data will be stored?

I am sorry if my questions are confusing but i just need some guidlines from where to begin...

thanks in advance

Comment: off-topic. Too broad. Also, if you use proper technology (not java) you can use something like LINQ to XML and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up two questions here:

1. How to store the questions on the server
2. How to transfer them to the device.

SQL is a good choice for the server side, you'll need to come up with some possibility to insert questions to your database, you'll probably not want to insert them with manual SQL statements. You can for example create a small Java applet that let's you insert them.

XML or JSON via a REST api seem to be the options that make the most sense. Serializing and deserializing them with [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) or [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is easy-peasy.

On how to secure your app/game against people just downloading all of your questions (and probably answers), can't really tell. I would guess that 'serious' quiz games use some forms of encryption and authentication there.